# How do I have a collision and reaction between two classes?

Tags: java, swing, awt, collision-detection

I have an array of type Dot which carries a Point and radius and a Player which is a rectangle with a Point and size.

I would to create a method which is constantly testing if the Player touches/collides with any of the dots in the array. Where would i write the code and what do i need to pass in as parameters?

This is for a game where the player must dodge dots. So far i have something like this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DOTS; i++) {
   if (player.intersects(dotPos[i])) {
      gameOver = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: See also these [questions and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+%5Bswing%5D+intersects).

Answer (score 1):

What front end technology are you using?  If Swing/AWT, they provide event listeners that can listen for changes.  For a web app, the submission/AJAX action is the even that can look for changes.

If you want to be really generic, you would need to create a new Thread and have your listener code in the run method.

Comment: You could use an action listener when the user changes direction.  There are specific ones like for the mouse. (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).  Or you can use javax.swing.Timer if the polling isn't tied to an event.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to use classes that implement the [`java.awt.Shape`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, then one of defined `intersects()` methods may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

also, lerp sounds like it may be helpful

Comment: Can you provide a link or more details?

Comment: lerp (linear interpolation) find the line between two points. if your player/dots are moving in a straight line constantly, you can use lerp to check whether a point/dot can/will ever come into contact with one another. lerp is fairly easy to implement, and is a common method in many languages - although i cant think of a basic lerp function in java  but check out the wiki page [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for a fairly succinct explanation of how to compute it

Comment: (the beauty of it is that you can check once whether the two may cross paths. if they wont, you wont need to keep polling whether they are colliding) i know it doesnt completely solve your problem, you'll need to use one of the other intersection methods, but it will help cut down your computation

Comment: Ah, I see the advantage. See also [`lerp()`](http://processing.org/reference/lerp_.html).

Answer (score 1):

> Where would i write the code and what do i need to pass in as parameters?

In your application you will have some event handler to detect when the user moves. Depending on the nature of the game you can do your check every time the user moves. Lets say you have using a keyListener, the in the keypressed event handler you can use the for loop that you have to determine collision.

In addition you may have a thread running that moves the dots (do the dots move?). This is another place where you can place the code to check for collisions.